# make a custom map with Google maps technology

Tags: google-maps, maps

For a project I made a map. I need zoom and scroll functionality for this map. I know there is a way to use the google maps technology for this. But I can't find the proper documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have generated your own custom map tiles and have a way of hosting them then the maps functionality you're looking for is documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes.